# Image Search Example via Rails Google API Client

Tags: google-app-engine, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api-client, google-custom-search

I need to replicate "**Search Google for this Image**" in my rails app where image search is performed on an image in the app. I am using [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) gem. To test the api I am starting with a simple query search:

Trying this for a regular search term but getting **invalid_scope** error.

```
client               = Google::APIClient.new application_name: 'xxx', application_version: '1.0'
keypath              = Rails.root.join('config', 'privatekey.p12').to_s
key                  = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(keypath, 'notasecret')

client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience             => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :scope                => 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1',
    :issuer               => 'xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    :signing_key          => key
).tap { |auth| auth.fetch_access_token! }


api_method = client.discovered_api('customsearch', 'v1')

result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {
    'q'          => 'Hello+World'
})
return result.data
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your API call is missing the required Custom Search Engine ID. You need to use cx or cref to specify the custom search engine you want to use. If you don't already have CSE ID, you can get one here: https://www.google.com/cse

Once you have the CSE ID, you will need to include it to the parameters. One possible way is just adding it to the hash you already have...

```
result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {'cx' => 'YOUR_CSE_ID', 'q'=> 'Hello+World'}
```

Your actual URI structure should look like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR_API_KEY&cx=YOUR_CSE_ID&q=Hello+World
```

Here's another good reference: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have experience with the Custom Search Engine but I did find a link I think could help you get to the right answer. This Google Dev documentation seems pretty good for setting up a custom search engine for your site.

[Google Developers - Creating a Custom Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse)